# Deleting a local file after download has finished

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a rather simple webapp, which has a button for exporting data to a csv file and then downloading it on the user's machine. The javascript code is rather simple:

```
function setCsvToDownload(csv_file_path) {
    var temp_download_link = document.createElement("a");
    temp_download_link.download = csv_file_path;
    temp_download_link.href = csv_file_path;
    temp_download_link.click();
  }
```

The problem I have is that I want to tell the backend to delete this local csv it wrote to after the download is finished on the user's end. Is there a way to figure out when a download is successfully finished?

Comment: You should post a [mcve] of your backend code instead of frontend code. You don't know when the download has finished but you can find out when the send has finished.

Comment: A different approach could be that a user frequently polls after the download starts and sends a confirmation after a successful download. If the polling stops without confirmation you know that the download wasn't successful.

Comment: How about generating the file in JavaScript and then downloading that?

Comment: You could also generate the content bases on URL parameters and write it to the response directly instead of creating a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I figured one can just encodeURI the contents of the csv file to download it without the need to write to a file on the disk. I'm rather new to web development, so I didn't know this was an option. Here is the code snippet for any other beginner like me, who encounters this problem (csv_name and csv_contents are sent from the bakcend)

```
function setCsvToDownload(csv_name, csv_contents) {
    var temp_download_link = document.createElement("a");
    temp_download_link.download = csv_name;
    temp_download_link.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8' + encodeURI(csv_contents);
    temp_download_link.target = '_blank';
    temp_download_link.click();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to figure out when a download is successfully finished?

No, there is not.

You should probably just have your backend periodically expire temporary CSV URLs after some time after their creation.

Comment: But it's possible to figure out when the server finished the send and I think that's the actual question.

Comment: @jabaa Depending on frameworks etc., yeah, it might be. However, if the client fails the download (e.g. out of disk space?) it might be a good idea to make it retriable.

Comment: I'd say _"exporting data to a csv file and then downloading it on the user's machine"_ is retriable

Comment: @jabaa My assumption there was that the generation of the CSV file is not necessarily fast or light (since they go through the extra bother of generating a CSV file on disk).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know when the client has finished the download.

Wouldn't it make more sense as other suggested to have the server delete the file on successful sending of the file?

Comment: Answers that include input from the OP are not really solutions to the question.